# What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, latitude-longitude

The `LocationManager` API on Android seems like it's a bit of a pain to use for an application that only needs an occasional and rough approximation of the user's location.

The app I'm working on isn't really a location app per se, but it does need to get the user's location in order to display a list of nearby businesses.  It doesn't need to worry about if the user is moving around or anything like that.

Here's what I'd like to do:

1. Show the user a list of nearby locations.
2. Preload the user's location so that by the time I need it in `Activity` X, it will be available.
3. I don't particularly care about accuracy or frequency of update. Just grabbing one location is sufficient as long as it's not way off. Maybe if I want to be fancy I'll update the location once every few mins or so, but it's not a huge priority.
4. Work for any device as long as it has either a GPS or a Network Location provider.

It seems like it shouldn't be that hard, but it appears to me that I have to spin up two different location providers (GPS and NETWORK) and manage each's lifecycle. Not only that, but I have to duplicate the same code in multiple activities to satisfy #2. I've tried using `getBestProvider()` in the past to cut the solution down to just using one location provider, but that seems to only give you the best "theoretical" provider rather than the provider that's actually going to give you the best results.

Is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could use a simple library that abstracts away all the things that must happen "under the hood": https://github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation

Comment: get the answer in Kotlin here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53800632/2201814

Comment: u can use fused location capturing techniques in android.

Comment: FusedLocation works fine (I still don't know why getCurrentLocation() had to be deprecated though).

Answer (score 969, accepted):

Here's what I do:

1. First of all I check what providers are enabled. Some may be disabled on the device, some may be disabled in application manifest.
2. If any provider is available I start location listeners and timeout timer. It's 20 seconds in my example, may not be enough for GPS so you can enlarge it.
3. If I get update from location listener I use the provided value. I stop listeners and timer.
4. If I don't get any updates and timer elapses I have to use last known values.
5. I grab last known values from available providers and choose the most recent of them.

Here's how I use my class:

```
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location){
        //Got the location!
    }
};
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
```

And here's MyLocation class:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

Somebody may also want to modify my logic. For example if you get update from Network provider don't stop listeners but continue waiting. GPS gives more accurate data so it's worth waiting for it. If timer elapses and you've got update from Network but not from GPS then you can use value provided from Network.

One more approach is to use LocationClient http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html. But it requires Google Play Services apk to be installed on user device.

Comment: Hi Fedor, thanks for that, it looks strikingly similar to what I ended up doing for previous projects.  And that's more or less what prompted this question: surely there must be a simpler way?!

Comment: I'm not aware of any simpler way. You can make modifications to my method. For example you may listen to only one provider instead of two. But anyway you need listener, timeout timer.

Comment: That's right. "android:configChanges" should be specified to avoid activity restart on orientation change. And if you still need to restart activity you should cancel TimerTask or even the complete Timer.

Comment: For the record, my understanding is that google generally recommends against using android:configChanges.  Instead I've gone with a solution that registers the timertasks and cancels them onDestroy.

Comment: Suggestion: we could also add a flag on timeout occur. Check [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#scheduledExecutionTime()). As GPS needs clear sky, timeout will occur often, if we user is not using network based location.

Comment: This worked great for me!  However, the activity I used this for me checks location on resume.  If the user backs out of the activity before the location is returned the application would crash.  I fixed this by adding this method to your MyLocation class.public     void cancelTimer() {
     timer1.cancel();
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
    }  I call this onPause() and that fixed the crash.

Comment: If both gps and network providers are enabled why not just use gps?

Comment: @Fedor: Could you explain what's the usage of LocationResult? There were syntax errors with your usage code. I don't understand what's side effect of keeping this class abstract. Thanks for demo anyway.

Comment: @Fedor can you tell me when i am using the network to find the location i found that while using the maps it is fetching very fast while in my application i am getting the location but little slower. its like while start the map it shows on the notification bar the fetching start instantly while in my application it start little later or some time not my timeout is 7sec to get either from network or from GPS.

Comment: In my case Fedor's code wasn't accurate at all without gps and I ended up using Commonsware location polling library (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll), which has given me much better results. I really don't know why, because both relay on the same basic code, but the accuracy improvement for network location is huge.

Comment: How to get the location with this piece of code ? Show me just how to toast it or seomthing.

Comment: @Fedor can you please tell the value of location is moving from where to where and where is the last value of location .

Comment: hello I'm using this code and inserting location.getLatitude(); and location.getLongitude(); but I'm getting 0.0 at the result,I've added access fine location in the permission and internet permission too,is there anything else I need to do?thanks

Comment: I want to use this function in handler because i am loading progress dialogbox while getting location but i am getting error like can not create handler in side loop.handler like that

Comment: Well it really looks like the code that should have been in Google's LocationManager in the first place. The important activity around this thread confirms it. Thanks for sharing @Fedor

Comment: @Fedor, I do have a question. I know that GPS will not work in a building, but if I set it to GPS only on the location and try to locate, the app force closes. Is there anything special I need to be doing to avoid the force close with just GPS enabled and no other location services?

Comment: Could it cause problems to convert LocationResult to an interface? I'd like an activity to implement it.

Comment: @Fedor Since 1 upvote isn't enough, I just wanted to make sure you know your answer is awesome.

Comment: Can you update the answer to mention new `LocationClient` API?

Comment: @MaciejGórski LocationClient depends on Google Play Services apk. In most cases you can live without it.

Comment: @Fedor i see that you consider as good enough the first location that you get, but what if its not? Also, you don't do anything with the other 3 methods from LocationListener.. shouldn't you take them into consideration? Thanks, im new to Android.

Comment: @Fedor how can i get New latitude and longitube values after every 5 seconds? where to update the code? please help

Comment: I've used this solution as a base to my own implementation. To avoid potential sync issues such as the one raised up by differenziale, I would suggest to not use `Timer`s and use `Handler`s on the caller thread.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html

Comment: If you forget to add the **USES-PERMISSION** you are going to have a bad time.

Comment: I tried both providers turned on in my htc one s, but it goes inside that,    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled){
          Log.v("Ansar",""+"Nothing Enabled");
            return false;
        }          ,why this?

Comment: @fedor,i saw your post,its nice one.but i want to get the current location by based  gps only .its possible.i have turn on only the gps and then turn off the network based location.so i can't get the current locations ,what can i do.hope you help me.

Comment: Not updating location after equal interval of time.  :(

Comment: @Fedor please tell me which is the best way to get the location update? Google Fusedlocation or  your way to get the location.

Comment: @Fedor how to get the location.getLatitude() & location.getLongitude() outside?

Comment: Also check this post, it's much more recent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation

Comment: @Fedor In location setting it's showing high battery uses. can't we make it to working on low battery uses?

Comment: what if I want to use fused location provider,it always return null for current location if location is not turned on device settings.

Comment: hi, your class is great and all, but how do i always get fresh location, every single time, no need for last known

Comment: do i need to put check permission here?

Comment: @Fedor what should we do if the device has not any `LastKnowLocation` and `internet connection`?

Comment: @Fedor thank you for your great answer. but I have a problem. exactly when gps turned on for first time, not **GPS** nor **Internet** providers working and return null. how can I solve this ?

Comment: gotLocation in initialize LocationResult never called for geting location

Answer (score 48):

After searching for best implementation how to get best precise user location I managed to combine all the best methods and come up with following class:

```
/**
 * Retrieve accurate location from GPS or network services. 
 * 
 *
 * Class usage example:
 * 
 * public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 *      ...
 *      my_location = new MyLocation();
 *      my_location.init(main.this, locationResult);
 * }
 * 
 * 
 * public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
 *      @Override
 *      public void gotLocation(final Location location){
 *          // do something
 *          location.getLongitude();
 *          location.getLatitude();
 *      }
 *  };
 */
class MyLocation{

    /**
     * If GPS is enabled. 
     * Use minimal connected satellites count.
     */
    private static final int min_gps_sat_count = 5;

    /**
     * Iteration step time.
     */
    private static final int iteration_timeout_step = 500;

    LocationResult locationResult;
    private Location bestLocation = null;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private LocationManager myLocationManager; 
    public Context context;

    private boolean gps_enabled = false;

    private int counts    = 0;
    private int sat_count = 0;

    private Runnable showTime = new Runnable() {
    
         public void run() {
            boolean stop = false;
            counts++;
            System.println("counts=" + counts);
            
            //if timeout (1 min) exceeded, stop tying
            if(counts > 120){
                stop = true;
            }
            
            //update last best location
            bestLocation = getLocation(context);
            
            //if location is not ready or don`t exists, try again
            if(bestLocation == null && gps_enabled){
                System.println("BestLocation not ready, continue to wait");
                handler.postDelayed(this, iteration_timeout_step);
            }else{
                //if best location is known, calculate if we need to continue to look for better location
                //if gps is enabled and min satellites count has not been connected or min check count is smaller then 4 (2 sec)  
                if(stop == false && !needToStop()){
                    System.println("Connected " + sat_count + " sattelites. continue waiting..");
                    handler.postDelayed(this, iteration_timeout_step);
                }else{
                    System.println("#########################################");
                    System.println("BestLocation found return result to main. sat_count=" + sat_count);
                    System.println("#########################################");

                    // removing all updates and listeners
                    myLocationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
                    myLocationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);    
                    myLocationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener);
                    sat_count = 0;
                    
                    // send best location to locationResult
                    locationResult.gotLocation(bestLocation);
                }
            }
         }
    };
        
    /**
     * Determine if continue to try to find best location
     */
    private Boolean needToStop(){

        if(!gps_enabled){
                          return true;
                     }
          else if(counts <= 4){
                return false;
            }
            if(sat_count < min_gps_sat_count){
                //if 20-25 sec and 3 satellites found then stop
                if(counts >= 40 && sat_count >= 3){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Best location abstract result class
     */
    public static abstract class LocationResult{
         public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
     }

    /**
     * Initialize starting values and starting best location listeners
     * 
     * @param Context ctx
     * @param LocationResult result
     */
    public void init(Context ctx, LocationResult result){
        context = ctx;
        locationResult = result;
    
        myLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    
        gps_enabled = (Boolean) myLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    
        bestLocation = null;
        counts = 0;
    
        // turning on location updates
        myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates("network", 0, 0, networkLocationListener);
        myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, gpsLocationListener);
        myLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener);
    
        // starting best location finder loop
        handler.postDelayed(showTime, iteration_timeout_step);
    }

    /**
     * GpsStatus listener. OnChainged counts connected satellites count.
     */
    public final GpsStatus.Listener gpsStatusListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {
        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        
             if(event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS){
                try {
                    // Check number of satellites in list to determine fix state
                     GpsStatus status = myLocationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
                     Iterable<GpsSatellite>satellites = status.getSatellites();
                     
                     sat_count = 0;
                     
                     Iterator<GpsSatellite>satI = satellites.iterator();
                     while(satI.hasNext()) {
                         GpsSatellite satellite = satI.next();
                         System.println("Satellite: snr=" + satellite.getSnr() + ", elevation=" + satellite.getElevation());                         
                         sat_count++;
                     }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    sat_count = min_gps_sat_count + 1;
                }
                 
                 System.println("#### sat_count = " + sat_count);
             }
         }
    };

    /**
     * Gps location listener.
     */
    public final LocationListener gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener(){
        @Override
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        
        }
         public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
         public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
         public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}
    }; 

    /**
     * Network location listener.
     */
    public final LocationListener networkLocationListener = new LocationListener(){
        @Override
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        
        }
         public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
         public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
         public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}
    }; 


    /**
     * Returns best location using LocationManager.getBestProvider()
     * 
     * @param context
     * @return Location|null
     */
    public static Location getLocation(Context context){
        System.println("getLocation()");
    
        // fetch last known location and update it
        try {
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
             
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
             criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
             criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
             criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
             String strLocationProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            
             System.println("strLocationProvider=" + strLocationProvider);
             Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(strLocationProvider);
             if(location != null){
                return location;
             }
             return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This class tries to connect to `min_gps_sat_count` satellites if GPS is enabled. Else returns `LocationManager.getBestProvider()` location. Check the code!

Comment: It will stop after 1 minute or when it will find location.

Comment: @wormhit In my case, its not getting stop after 120 count. I have enabled the GPS and network provider is also available also I have added the appropriate permissio in Menifest file.

Comment: Just put these as import: `import java.util.Iterator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.GpsSatellite;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;`

Answer (score 33):

With Fedor's solution I've experienced multiple execution of the callback `gotLocation`.
It seems to be due to a **race condition** in the overridden `LocationListener.onLocationChanged` method, when gotLocation method is *'long enough'*. I'm not sure, but I guess `removeUpdates` prevents the enqueueing of new messages in the Looper queue, but it doesn't remove those already enqueued but not yet consumed. Hence the race condition.

To reduce the probability of this wrong behavior it's possible to call removeUpdates before firing the onLocationChanged event, but still we have the race condition.

The best solution I found is to replace `requestLocationUpdates` with `requestSingleUpdate`.

This is my version, based on Fedor's solution, using an Handler to send a message to the looper thread:

```
public class LocationResolver {
    private Timer timer;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationResult locationResult;
    private boolean gpsEnabled = false;
    private boolean networkEnabled = false;
    private Handler locationTimeoutHandler;

    private final Callback locationTimeoutCallback = new Callback() {
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            locationTimeoutFunc();
            return true;
        }

        private void locationTimeoutFunc() {   
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

            Location networkLocation = null, gpsLocation = null;
            if (gpsEnabled)
                gpsLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (networkEnabled)
                networkLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            // if there are both values use the latest one
            if (gpsLocation != null && networkLocation != null) {
                if (gpsLocation.getTime() > networkLocation.getTime())
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gpsLocation);
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(networkLocation);
                return;
            }

            if (gpsLocation != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(gpsLocation);
                return;
            }
            if (networkLocation != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(networkLocation);
                return;
            }
            locationResult.gotLocation(null);           
        }
    };
    private final LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {              
            timer.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
    private final LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {    
            timer.cancel(); 
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    public void prepare() {
        locationTimeoutHandler = new Handler(locationTimeoutCallback);
    }

    public synchronized boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result, int maxMillisToWait) {
        locationResult = result;
        if (locationManager == null)
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try {
            gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            networkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        // don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if (!gpsEnabled && !networkEnabled)
            return false;

        if (gpsEnabled)
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, locationListenerGps, Looper.myLooper());
            //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if (networkEnabled)
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, locationListenerNetwork, Looper.myLooper());
            //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new GetLastLocationTask(), maxMillisToWait);
        return true;
    }

    private class GetLastLocationTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
            locationTimeoutHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult {
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

I use this class from a customized looper thread, like the following one:

```
public class LocationGetter {
    private final Context context;
    private Location location = null;
    private final Object gotLocationLock = new Object();
    private final LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {            
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            synchronized (gotLocationLock) {
                LocationGetter.this.location = location;
                gotLocationLock.notifyAll();
                Looper.myLooper().quit();
            }
        }
    };

    public LocationGetter(Context context) {
        if (context == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("context == null");

        this.context = context;
    }

    public synchronized Coordinates getLocation(int maxWaitingTime, int updateTimeout) {
        try {
            final int updateTimeoutPar = updateTimeout;
            synchronized (gotLocationLock) {            
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        Looper.prepare();
                        LocationResolver locationResolver = new LocationResolver();
                        locationResolver.prepare();
                        locationResolver.getLocation(context, locationResult, updateTimeoutPar);
                        Looper.loop();
                    }
                }.start();

                gotLocationLock.wait(maxWaitingTime);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (location != null)
            coordinates = new Coordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        else
            coordinates = Coordinates.UNDEFINED;
        return coordinates; 
    }
}
```

where Coordinates is a simple class with two properties: latitude and longitude.

Comment: Interesting point, anyway, requestSingleUpdate requires API Level 9. But +1 for pointing that out.

Comment: @Eduardo: another possibility is to execute the code of the task using an Handler associated to the looper and calling it by sending an (empty) message to the handler. Since messages are serialized on the looper queue, you can remove manually (e.g. using a flag) the race condition. That doesn't require API Livel 9, but it needs to use explicitly the looper.

Answer (score 19):

I have created small application with step by step description to gets current locations GPS co-ordinates.

[image]

***Complete example source code in below URL:***

---

> [**Get Current Location coordinates , City name - in Android**](http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html)

---

**See How it works :**

- All we need to do is add this permission in manifest file

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">  
  </uses-permission>
  ```
- and create LocationManager instance like this

  ```
  LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                                    getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  ```
- Check GPS is enabled or not
- then implement LocationListener and Get Coordinates

  ```
  LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();  
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(  
  LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
  ```
- here is the sample code to do

---

```
/*----------Listener class to get coordinates ------------- */
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        editLocation.setText("");
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(
            getBaseContext(),
            "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
        Log.v(TAG, longitude);
        String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
        Log.v(TAG, latitude);
        /*-------to get City-Name from coordinates -------- */
        String cityName = null;
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                loc.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0)
                System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
            cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String s = longitude + "\n" + latitude + "\n\nMy Current City is: "
            + cityName;
        editLocation.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Comment: location need to be change. not while standing.

Answer (score 18):

You could always just use [LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) but like it says it could be out of date.

And a simple way to get a general location could be registering for the network (usually pretty fast).

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
     LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1000, this);
```

and then doing

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

in the `onLocationChanged()` method of the listener.

Comment: Thanks BrennaSoft.  I've found that getLastKnownLocation() can often be wildly off, and therefore doesn't really work as a standalone solution.  

Also, it's not clear to me that solely relying on the NETWORK_PROVIDER will work, since many areas of the country don't have very good GPS coordinates for wifi access points (and I don't know about cell towers)

Answer (score 11):

I have written detailed tutorial covering [current location](https://demonuts.com/android-get-current-location/) here on [demonuts.com](http://demonuts.com).You can find more description here and also you can download whole demo source code for better understanding.

There are already many answers there but I want to show latest way to get location using Google API, so new programmers can use new method:

First of all, put this in gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

then implement necessary interfaces

```
public class MainActivity  extends BaseActivitiy implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
```

declare instances

```
  private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
  private Location mLocation;
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
```

put this in `onCreate()`

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

At last, override necessary methods

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }
```

Don't forget to start GPS in your device before running app.

Comment: Using API ? So this is service is rate limited right.

Answer (score 10):

Actualy we can use the two providers(GPS & NETWORK). And they just share a public listener:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10 * 1000, (float) 10.0, listener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 90 * 1000, (float) 10.0, listener);
```

This is necessary because the `OnLocationChanged()` method always need to be called in time.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if the [Location-Based Services](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/location/) can get the location from other infrastructures other than GPS, but according to that article, it does seem possible:

> Applications can call on any of
>   several types of positioning methods.
>
> Using the mobile phone network: The
>   current cell ID can be used to
>   identify the Base Transceiver Station
>   (BTS) that the device is communicating
>   with and the location of that BTS.
>   Clearly, the accuracy of this method
>   depends on the size of the cell, and
>   can be quite inaccurate. A GSM cell
>   may be anywhere from 2 to 20
>   kilometers in diameter. Other
>   techniques used along with cell ID can
>   achieve accuracy within 150 meters.
>
> Using satellites: The Global
>   Positioning System (GPS), controlled
>   by the US Department of Defense, uses
>   a constellation of 24 satellites
>   orbiting the earth. GPS determines the
>   device's position by calculating
>   differences in the times signals from
>   different satellites take to reach the
>   receiver. GPS signals are encoded, so
>   the mobile device must be equipped
>   with a GPS receiver. GPS is
>   potentially the most accurate method
>   (between 4 and 40 meters if the GPS
>   receiver has a clear view of the sky),
>   but it has some drawbacks: The extra
>   hardware can be costly, consumes
>   battery while in use, and requires
>   some warm-up after a cold start to get
>   an initial fix on visible satellites.
>   It also suffers from "canyon effects"
>   in cities, where satellite visibility
>   is intermittent.
>
> Using short-range
>   positioning beacons: In relatively
>   small areas, such as a single
>   building, a local area network can
>   provide locations along with other
>   services. For example, appropriately
>   equipped devices can use Bluetooth for
>   short-range positioning.

Comment: @ElijahSaounkine apparently npinti hasn't heard of Assisted GPS. In the future you could perhaps just inform people of things they've overseen, instead of being aggressive about it.

Comment: @Sammy 5 years ago I seem to have been much jumpier than now. "The future" you refer to, in relation to my note, has probably already started and ended ;)

Answer (score 7):

Use the below code, it will give the best provider available:

```
String locCtx = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE; 

LocationManager locationMgr = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(locCtx);

Criteria criteria  = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

String provider = locationMgr.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

System.out.println("Best Available provider::::"+provider);
```

Comment: how to initialize ctx, Context ctx= this; ? it crashed

Answer (score 6):

The recommended way to do this is to use `LocationClient`:

First, define location update interval values. Adjust this to your needs.

```
private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 1;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
```

Have your `Activity` implement `GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks`, `GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`, and `LocationListener`.

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements 
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {}
```

Then, set up a `LocationClient`in the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
}
```

Add the required methods to your `Activity`; `onConnected()` is the method that is called when the `LocationClient`connects. `onLocationChanged()` is where you'll retrieve the most up-to-date location.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Location client connection failed");
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location client connected");
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this); 
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location client disconnected");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Updated Location: " + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Updated location NULL");
    } 
}
```

Be sure to connect/disconnect the `LocationClient` so it's only using extra battery when absolutely necessary and so the GPS doesn't run indefinitely. The `LocationClient` must be connected in order to get data from it.

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

public void onStop() {
    if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
    }
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Get the user's location. First try using the `LocationClient`; if that fails, fall back to the `LocationManager`.

```
public Location getLocation() {
    if (mLocationClient != null && mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        return mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    } else {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            Location lastKnownLocationGPS = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (lastKnownLocationGPS != null) {
                return lastKnownLocationGPS;
            } else {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Even though the answer is already given here. I just wanted to share this to the world incase the come across such scenario.

My requirement was that i needed to get a user's current location within 30 to 35 seconds at max so here is the solution i made following [Nirav Ranpara's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15757944/1118886).

**1.** I made **MyLocationManager.java** class which handles all the GPS and Network stuff

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.app.callbacks.OnLocationDetectectionListener;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyLocationManager {
    /** The minimum distance to GPS change Updates in meters **/
    private final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES_FOR_GPS = 2; // 2
                                                                    // meters
    /** The minimum time between GPS updates in milliseconds **/
    private final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES_OF_GPS = 1000 * 5 * 1; // 5
                                                                    // seconds

    /** The minimum distance to NETWORK change Updates in meters **/
    private final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES_FOR_NETWORK = 5; // 5
                                                                        // meters
    /** The minimum time between NETWORK updates in milliseconds **/
    private final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES_OF_NETWORK = 1000 * 10 * 1; // 10
                                                                        // seconds

    /**
     * Lets just say i don't trust the first location that the is found. This is
     * to avoid that
     **/

    private int NetworkLocationCount = 0, GPSLocationCount = 0;
    private boolean isGPSEnabled;
    private boolean isNetworkEnabled;
    /**
     * Don't do anything if location is being updated by Network or by GPS
     */
    private boolean isLocationManagerBusy;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnLocationDetectectionListener mListener;

    public MyLocationManager(Context mContext,
            OnLocationDetectectionListener mListener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    /**
     * Start the location manager to find my location
     */
    public void startLocating() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // Getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // No network provider is enabled
                showSettingsAlertDialog();
            } else {
                // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES_OF_GPS,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES_FOR_GPS,
                            gpsLocationListener);

                }
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES_OF_NETWORK,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES_FOR_NETWORK,
                            networkLocationListener);

                }
            }
            /**
             * My 30 seconds plan to get myself a location
             */
            ScheduledExecutorService se = Executors
                    .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            se.schedule(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (currentLocation == null) {
                        if (isGPSEnabled) {
                            currentLocation = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        } else if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                            currentLocation = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        }
                        if (currentLocation != null && mListener != null) {
                            locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
                            locationManager
                                    .removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);
                            mListener.onLocationDetected(currentLocation);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error Fetching Location", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(mContext,
                    "Error Fetching Location" + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle GPS location listener callbacks
     */
    private LocationListener gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if (GPSLocationCount != 0 && !isLocationManagerBusy) {
                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                isLocationManagerBusy = true;
                currentLocation = location;
                locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
                locationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);
                isLocationManagerBusy = false;
                if (currentLocation != null && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onLocationDetected(currentLocation);
                }
            }
            GPSLocationCount++;
        }
    };
    /**
     * Handle Network location listener callbacks
     */
    private LocationListener networkLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (NetworkLocationCount != 0 && !isLocationManagerBusy) {
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                isLocationManagerBusy = true;
                currentLocation = location;
                locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
                locationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);
                isLocationManagerBusy = false;
                if (currentLocation != null && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onLocationDetected(currentLocation);
                }
            }
            NetworkLocationCount++;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog. On pressing the Settings button
     * it will launch Settings Options.
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing the Settings button.
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // On pressing the cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

**2.** I made an Interface (callback) **OnLocationDetectectionListener.java** in order to communicate the results back to the calling fragment or activity

```
import android.location.Location;

public interface OnLocationDetectectionListener {
    public void onLocationDetected(Location mLocation);
}
```

**3.** Then i made an **MainAppActivty.java** Activity that implements `OnLocationDetectectionListener` interface and here is how i receive my location in it

```
public class MainAppActivty extends Activity implements
        OnLocationDetectectionListener {

    private Location currentLocation;
    private MyLocationManager mLocationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mLocationManager = new MyLocationManager(this, this);
            mLocationManager.startLocating();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationDetected(Location mLocation) {
        //Your new Location is received here
        currentLocation = mLocation;
    }
```

**4.** Add the following permissions to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Hope this is helpful to others :)

Answer (score 4):

Improvements to @Fedor's solution.
Rather than requesting location with '0' time interval and '0' distance, we can use the location manager's **requestSingleUpdate** method. Updated code(kotlin version)

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.location.Criteria
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Bundle
import java.util.*

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
class AppLocationProvider {

  private lateinit var timer: Timer
  private var locationManager: LocationManager? = null
  private lateinit var locationCallBack: LocationCallBack
  private var gpsEnabled = false
  private var networkEnabled = false

  private var locationListener: LocationListener = object : LocationListener {

    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
      timer.cancel()
      locationCallBack.locationResult(location)
    }

    override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
    override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
    override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}
  }

  fun getLocation(context : Context, callBack: LocationCallBack): Boolean {
    locationCallBack = callBack
    if (locationManager == null)
      locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager?

    //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
    try {
      gpsEnabled = locationManager!!.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
      ex.printStackTrace()
    }

    try {
      networkEnabled = locationManager!!.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
      ex.printStackTrace()
    }

    //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
    if (!gpsEnabled && !networkEnabled)
      return false

    val criteria = Criteria()
    if (gpsEnabled) {
      criteria.accuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
    } else {
      criteria.accuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE
    }
    locationManager!!.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, locationListener, null)

    timer = Timer()
    timer.schedule(GetLastKnownLocation(), 5000)
    return true
  }

  inner class GetLastKnownLocation : TimerTask() {

    override fun run() {
      locationManager!!.removeUpdates(locationListener)

      var netLoc: Location? = null
      var gpsLoc: Location? = null

      if (gpsEnabled)
        gpsLoc = locationManager!!.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
      if (networkEnabled)
        netLoc = locationManager!!.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)

      //check which value use the latest one
      if (gpsLoc != null && netLoc != null) {
        if (gpsLoc.time > netLoc.time)
          locationCallBack.locationResult(gpsLoc)
        else
          locationCallBack.locationResult(netLoc)
        return
      }

      if (gpsLoc != null) {
        locationCallBack.locationResult(gpsLoc)
        return
      }
      if (netLoc != null) {
        locationCallBack.locationResult(netLoc)
        return
      }
      locationCallBack.locationResult(null)
    }
  }

  interface LocationCallBack {
    fun locationResult(location: Location?)
  }
}
```

To get location need to just call getLocation method as -

```
AppLocationProvider().getLocation(context, object : AppLocationProvider.LocationCallBack {
  override fun locationResult(location: Location?) {
    // use location, this might get called in a different thread if a location is a last known location. In that case, you can post location on main thread
  }
})
```

**Note:**
Before calling getLocation method, required location permission must be granted.

Comment: `LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate` is now deprecated in 2021.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static Location getBestLocation(Context ctxt) {
    Location gpslocation = getLocationByProvider(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, ctxt);
    Location networkLocation = getLocationByProvider(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, ctxt);
    Location fetchedlocation = null;
    // if we have only one location available, the choice is easy
    if (gpslocation != null) {
        Log.i("New Location Receiver", "GPS Location available.");
        fetchedlocation = gpslocation;
    } else {
        Log.i("New Location Receiver",
            "No GPS Location available. Fetching Network location lat="
                + networkLocation.getLatitude() + " lon ="
                + networkLocation.getLongitude());
        fetchedlocation = networkLocation;
    }
    return fetchedlocation;
}

/**
 * get the last known location from a specific provider (network/gps)
 */
private static Location getLocationByProvider(String provider, Context ctxt) {
    Location location = null;
    // if (!isProviderSupported(provider)) {
    // return null;
    // }
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) ctxt
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.i("New Location Receiver", "Cannot access Provider " + provider);
    }
    return location;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I am requesting User Permissions.

Outside your application tag in AndroidManifest.xml add these permission requests.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Then add Google's Location dependencies in the App Gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
```

Now declare some Global variables.

```
private lateinit var mFusedLocationProvider:FusedLocationProviderClient
private lateinit var mLocationCallback: LocationCallback
private lateinit var mLocationRequest: LocationRequest
private var mLocationPermissionGranted:Boolean = false
```

In OnCreate method of your Activity (I was not able to Format the Code Properly, Apology for that)

```
mFusedLocationProvider = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

//Location Callback
mLocationCallback = object: LocationCallback(){
 override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
  if(p0==null){
     //todo(request user to enable location from settings then remove return)
     return
  }else{
      getDeviceLocation()
       }
  }
}

//Location Request
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
//Set the Interval for Latest Interval Update
mLocationRequest.interval = 5000
//Set How Many Location Updated you Want
mLocationRequest.numUpdates = 1

getLocationPermission()
getDeviceLocation()
```

Now create both the functions.

```
 private fun getLocationPermission() {

            val permission:Array<String> = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext,Constant.FINE_LOCATION)== PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext,Constant.COARSE_LOCATION)== PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true
                }
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permission,Constant.LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE)
            }

    }
```

Second Method

```
private fun getDeviceLocation() {
        try{
            if(mLocationPermissionGranted){

                mFusedLocationProvider.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this,{task: Task<Location> ->
                    if(task.isSuccessful){
                        var currentLocation: Location? = task.result
                        if(currentLocation!=null){

                            Log.i("Location","Latitude is ${currentLocation.latitude} and Longitude" +
                                    "${currentLocation.longitude}")
                        }

                        else
                            mFusedLocationProvider.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,mLocationCallback,null)
                    }
                })
            }
        }catch (e:SecurityException){
            Log.e("Error", "Security Exception ${e.message}")
        }
    }
```

For Constant.kt

```
class Constant{
    companion object {

        //Location Request Settings
        const val SET_INTERVAL:Long = 2000
        const val NUM_UPDATES:Int = 1

        //Location Permission
        const val FINE_LOCATION:String = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        const val COARSE_LOCATION:String = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From last more than one year, I was using the combination of GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER to get the current location and it was working good, but from last few months I'm getting location after a long delay, so I switched to latest API FusedLocationProviderClient and it is working pretty good.

Here is the class which I wrote to get current location by using FusedLocationProviderClient.
In below code, I used a timer to wait for while to get the current location, I scheduled timer 15 seconds delay, you can change it according to you.

```
private static FusedLocationService ourInstance;
private final LocationRequest locationRequest;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private Context context;
private FindOutLocation findOutLocation;
private boolean callbackTriggered = false;
private Timer timer;

public static FusedLocationService getInstance(Context pContext) {

    if (null == ourInstance) ourInstance = new FusedLocationService(pContext);

    return ourInstance;
}

private FusedLocationService(Context pContext) {
    context = pContext;
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
    locationRequest = getLocationRequest();
    requestLocation(context);
}

public Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    return mLastLocation;
}

private void requestLocation(Context context) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
        if (location != null) {
            mLastLocation = location;
            triggerCallback(mLastLocation);
        }
    });
}

private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    long INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;
    long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 5 * 1000;
    locationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    return locationRequest;
}

private LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            if (location != null) mLastLocation = location;
        }
        if (null != mLastLocation) triggerCallback(mLastLocation);
    }
};

public static abstract class FindOutLocation {
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void findLocation(FindOutLocation findOutLocation) {
    long TIMER_TIME_OUT = 15 * 1000;
    this.findOutLocation = findOutLocation;
    callbackTriggered = false;

    try {
        requestLocation(context);
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new GetLastLocation(context), TIMER_TIME_OUT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
    Context context;

    GetLastLocation(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        triggerCallback(mLastLocation);
    }
}

private void triggerCallback(Location location) {
    if (null != location) mLastLocation = location;
    if (!callbackTriggered && null != findOutLocation) {
        callbackTriggered = true;
        removeLocationUpdates();
        findOutLocation.gotLocation(location);
        findOutLocation = null;
    }
}

private void removeLocationUpdates() {
    if (null != timer) timer.cancel();
    if (null != mFusedLocationClient)
        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
}
}
```

And called this from activity, here is the code

```
    FusedLocationService.FindOutLocation findOutLocation = new FusedLocationService.FindOutLocation() {
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location currentLocation) {
            if (currentLocation != null) {
                /*TODO DO SOMETHING WITH CURRENT LOCATION*/
            }
        }
    };
    FusedLocationService.getInstance(this).findLocation(findOutLocation);
```

Add following entries in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Needed only if your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Answer (score 2):

To get and show the user's current location, you could also use `MyLocationOverlay`. Suppose you have a `mapView` field in your activity. All you would need to do to show the user location is the following:

```
myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
```

This gets the current location from either the GPS or the network. If both fail, `enableMyLocation()` will return `false`.

As for the locations of things around the area, an `ItemizedOverlay` should do the trick.

I hope I haven't misunderstood your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that provides user current location

**create Maps Activty:**

```
public class Maps extends MapActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "MapActivity";
    private MapView mapView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    Location location;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    CountDownTimer locationtimer;
    MapController mapController;
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initComponents();
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapView.setTraffic(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(16);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager == null) {
            Toast.makeText(Maps.this, "Location Manager Not Available",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location == null)
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(Maps.this, "Location Are" + lat + ":" + lng,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
            mapController.animateTo(point, new Message());
            mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
            List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            listOfOverlays.clear();
            listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
        }
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}

            public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
                location = l;
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                if (l.getLatitude() == 0 || l.getLongitude() == 0) {
                } else {
                    double lat = l.getLatitude();
                    double lng = l.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(Maps.this, "Location Are" + lat + ":" + lng,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
        locationtimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 5000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (location != null) locationtimer.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (location == null) {
                }
            }
        };
        locationtimer.start();
    }

    public MapView getMapView() {
        return this.mapView;
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_container);
        ImageView ivhome = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView_home);
        ivhome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Maps.this, GridViewContainer.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    class MapOverlay extends Overlay {

        private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

        public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
            pointToDraw = point;
        }

        public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
            return pointToDraw;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
                long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.select_map);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**main.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:apiKey="yor api key"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**and define following permission in manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Updated with the latest *Location Service API* from Google Play Services library (July 2014)**

I would recommend you to use the new [Location Service API](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html), available from the Google Play Services library, which provides a more powerful, high-level framework that automates tasks such as location provider choice and power management. According to the official documentation: "... Location API make it easy for you to build location-aware applications, without needing to focus on the details of the underlying location technology. They also let you minimize power consumption by using all of the capabilities of the device hardware."

For further information visit: [Making Your App Location-Aware](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)

To see a full example using the latest Location Service API visit: [Android LocationClient class is deprecated but used in documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation/25173057#25173057)

Answer (score 1):

It requires lots of things in place to get location updates in android,
requires lots of bolierplate code.

You need to take care of

- Google Play services availablity Check,
- Update Google play Service if it is old or not available
- Dialog Creation of GoogleApiClient and its callbacks connected,disconnected etc.
- Stopping and releasing resources for location updates
- Handling Location permission scenarios
- Checking Location services are On or Off
- Getting lastknown location is not so easy either
- Fallback to last known location if not getting location after certain duration

I have created [Android-EasyLocation (small android library)](https://github.com/akhgupta/Android-EasyLocation) which will take care all this stuff and you can focus on business logic.

All you need is extend **EasyLocationActivity** and this

```
requestSingleLocationFix(easyLocationRequest);
```

or

```
requestLocationUpdates(easyLocationRequest);
```

Checkout sample app and steps needed here at https://github.com/akhgupta/Android-EasyLocation

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version of @Fedor **Greate** answer:

**usage of class:**

```
val locationResult = object : MyLocation.LocationResult() {

    override fun gotLocation(location: Location?) {

        val lat = location!!.latitude
        val lon = location.longitude

        Toast.makeText(context, "$lat --SLocRes-- $lon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}

val myLocation = MyLocation()
myLocation.getLocation(inflater.context, locationResult)
```

**`MyLocation` Class :**

```
class MyLocation {
    internal lateinit var timer1: Timer
    internal var lm: LocationManager? = null
    internal lateinit var locationResult: LocationResult
    internal var gps_enabled = false
    internal var network_enabled = false

    internal var locationListenerGps: LocationListener = object : LocationListener {


        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
            timer1.cancel()
            locationResult.gotLocation(location)
            lm!!.removeUpdates(this)
            lm!!.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork)
        }

        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
        override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
        override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}
    }

    internal var locationListenerNetwork: LocationListener = object : LocationListener {
        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
            timer1.cancel()
            locationResult.gotLocation(location)
            lm!!.removeUpdates(this)
            lm!!.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps)
        }

        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
        override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
        override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}
    }

    fun getLocation(context: Context, result: LocationResult): Boolean {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult = result
        if (lm == null)
            lm = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager?

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm!!.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
        }

        try {
            network_enabled = lm!!.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
        }

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) run {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION), 111)
        }


        if (gps_enabled)
            lm!!.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0f, locationListenerGps)
        if (network_enabled)
            lm!!.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0f, locationListenerNetwork)
        timer1 = Timer()
        timer1.schedule(GetLastLocation(context), 20000)
        return true
    }

    internal inner class GetLastLocation(var context: Context) : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            lm!!.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps)
            lm!!.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork)

            var net_loc: Location? = null
            var gps_loc: Location? = null

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) run {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),111)
            }


            if (gps_enabled)
                gps_loc = lm!!.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
            if (network_enabled)
                net_loc = lm!!.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)

            //if there are both values use the latest one
            if (gps_loc != null && net_loc != null) {
                if (gps_loc.getTime() > net_loc.getTime())
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc)
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc)
                return
            }

            if (gps_loc != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc)
                return
            }
            if (net_loc != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc)
                return
            }
            locationResult.gotLocation(null)
        }
    }

     abstract class LocationResult {
          abstract fun gotLocation(location: Location?)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and best way for GeoLocation.**

```
LocationManager lm = null;
boolean network_enabled;


if (lm == null)
                lm = (LocationManager) Kikit.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Kikit.this, "", "Fetching location...", true);


            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {

                            Log.e("counter value","value "+counter);

                            if(counter<=8)
                            {
                                try 
                                {
                                    counter++;


                                    if (network_enabled) {

                                        lm = (LocationManager) Kikit.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                                        Log.e("in network_enabled..","in network_enabled");

                                        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
                                        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() 
                                        {


                                            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
                                            {
                                                if(attempt == false)

                                                {
                                                    attempt = true;
                                                    Log.e("in location listener..","in location listener..");
                                                    longi = location.getLongitude();
                                                    lati = location.getLatitude();
                                                    Data.longi = "" + longi; 
                                                    Data.lati = "" + lati;


                                                    Log.e("longitude : ",""+longi);
                                                    Log.e("latitude : ",""+lati);



                                                    if(faceboo_name.equals(""))
                                                    {
                                                        if(dialog!=null){
                                                        dialog.cancel();}
                                                        timer.cancel();
                                                        timer.purge();
                                                        Data.homepage_resume = true;
                                                        lm = null;
                                                        Intent intent = new Intent();                              
                                                        intent.setClass(Kikit.this,MainActivity.class);

                                                        startActivity(intent);      
                                                        finish();
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {           

                                                        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

                                                        if (isInternetPresent) 
                                                        {
                                                            if(dialog!=null)
                                                                dialog.cancel();

                                                            Showdata();
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            error_view.setText(Data.internet_error_msg);
                                                            error_view.setVisibility(0);
                                                            error_gone();
                                                        }

                                                    }   
                                                }

                                            }

                                            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                                    Bundle extras) {
                                            }

                                            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            }

                                            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


                                            }
                                        };



                                        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive
                                        // location updates
                                        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100000, 10,locationListener);

                                    } else{
                                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection.", 2000).show();
                                        buildAlertMessageNoGps();

                                    }



                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // TODO
                                    // Auto-generated
                                    // catch
                                    // block
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                timer.purge();
                                timer.cancel();

                                if(attempt == false)
                                {
                                    attempt = true;

                                    String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
                                    // Or use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

                                    try {
                                        Location lastKnownLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

                                        longi = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
                                        lati = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
                                        Data.longi = "" + longi; 
                                        Data.lati = "" + lati;
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Log.i("exception in loc fetch", e.toString());
                                    }

                                    Log.e("longitude of last known location : ",""+longi);
                                    Log.e("latitude of last known location : ",""+lati);

                                    if(Data.fb_access_token == "")
                                    {

                                        if(dialog!=null){
                                            dialog.cancel();}
                                        timer.cancel();
                                        timer.purge();
                                        Data.homepage_resume = true;
                                        Intent intent = new Intent();                              
                                        intent.setClass(Kikit.this,MainActivity.class);

                                        startActivity(intent);  
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {           

                                        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

                                        if (isInternetPresent) 
                                        {
                                            if(dialog!=null){
                                                dialog.cancel();}           
                                            Showdata();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            error_view.setText(Data.internet_error_msg);
                                            error_view.setVisibility(0);
                                            error_gone();
                                        }

                                    }   

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 2000);


private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage("Your WiFi & mobile network location is disabled , do you want to enable it?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) 
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                setting_page = true;
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
                finish();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late here but what I would in such a situation is to use Google Maps API and mark the nearby locations using lat and long API of google maps. Plus user experience is better if you can show his/her location on a map. No need to bother about the updation of user location or frisking with android api. Let google maps handle the internals for you.

@emmby may have got it resolved in his app but for future reference a look at Google maps API for location specific stuff is what I recommend to fellow developers.

Edit: Link for displaying [user location in google maps](http://www.javaexperience.com/how-to-display-user-location-on-google-maps-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

1. First of all I check whether NETWORK or GPS providers are enabled. Some may be disabled on the device, some may be disabled in application manifest. If any provider is enabled, I fetch cached last location for this provider and start location update listeners for this provider.
2. There is a method to determine whether a location is better than last received location as mentioned in link :- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate
3. If I get update from location listener I check whether this location is better than previously received location. and If it is better than replace this location to previous best location(`mFinalLocation`).
4. There is also a handler(timer) for two minutes, which eventually stops the service and in `onDestroy()` method of service, stop listening for location updates for each of the provider.

Below is the code for service. You can run it based upon frequency of location update you need.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;


public class RecordLocationService extends Service {

    private final String TAG = RecordLocationService.class.getSimpleName();

    private final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;

    private LocationManager mLocationManager;

    private MyLocationListener mLocationListeners[] = new MyLocationListener[]{
            new MyLocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER),
            new MyLocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
    };

    private Location mFinalLocation;

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        private String mProvider;

        public MyLocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "LocationListener : " + provider);
            mProvider = provider;
        }

        public String getProvider() {
            return mProvider;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged : " + location);

            if (isBetterLocation(location, mFinalLocation)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Setting current Final Location to recent most Location for Provider : " + location.getProvider());
                Log.d(TAG, "Setting current Final Location to : " + location);
                mFinalLocation = location;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Keeping current Final Location to previous Final Location");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged provider " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onProviderEnabled provider " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onProviderDisabled provider " + provider);
        }
    }

    private Handler mStopServiceHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 1: {
                    stopSelf();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        requestLocation();
        mStopServiceHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, TWO_MINUTES);
    }

    private void requestLocation() {
        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }

        try {
            if (mLocationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) && mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Fetching Cached Location for Provider : " + LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                Location cachedNetworkLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (cachedNetworkLocation != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Setting Final Location to Cached Location for Provider : " + LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Setting Final Location to : " + cachedNetworkLocation);
                    mFinalLocation = cachedNetworkLocation;
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Cached Location for Provider : " + LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER + " is NULL");
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Location Update for Provider : " + LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListeners[0]);
            }

        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.e(TAG, se.getMessage(), se);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            Log.e(TAG, iae.getMessage(), iae);
        }

        try {
            if (mLocationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Fetching Cached Location for Provider : " + LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                Location cachedGPSLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                if (cachedGPSLocation != null) {
                    if (isBetterLocation(cachedGPSLocation, mFinalLocation)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Setting Final Location to Cached Location for Provider : " + LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Setting Final Location to : " + cachedGPSLocation);
                        mFinalLocation = cachedGPSLocation;
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Cached Location for Provider : " + LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER + " is NULL");
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Location Update for Provider : " + LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListeners[1]);
            }

        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.e(TAG, se.getMessage(), se);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            Log.e(TAG, iae.getMessage(), iae);
        }


    }

    /**
     * Determines whether one Location reading is better than the current Location fix
     *
     * @param location            The new Location that you want to evaluate
     * @param currentBestLocation The current Location fix, to which you want to compare the new one
     */
    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether two providers are the same
     */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Removing Location Update for Provider : " + mLocationListeners[i].getProvider());
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "fail to remove location listeners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity Class makes a customized method :

```
private void getTheUserPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationGetter locationGetter = new LocationGetter(FreshMenuSearchActivity.this, REQUEST_LOCATION, locationManager);


        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            locationGetter.OnGPS();
        } else {

            locationGetter.getLocation();
        }
    }
```

Make a UserDefined Class name LocationGetter:-

```
public class LocationGetter {

        private int REQUEST_LOCATION;
        private FreshMenuSearchActivity mContext;
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private Geocoder geocoder;

        public LocationGetter(FreshMenuSearchActivity mContext, int requestLocation, LocationManager locationManager) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.locationManager = locationManager;
            this.REQUEST_LOCATION = requestLocation;
        }


        public void getLocation() {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,

                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mContext, new String[]
                        {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
            } else {
                Location LocationGps = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                Location LocationNetwork = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                Location LocationPassive = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

                if (LocationGps != null) {
                    double lat = LocationGps.getLatitude();
                    double longi = LocationGps.getLongitude();
                    getTheAddress(lat, longi);
                } else if (LocationNetwork != null) {
                    double lat = LocationNetwork.getLatitude();
                    double longi = LocationNetwork.getLongitude();
                    getTheAddress(lat, longi);
                } else if (LocationPassive != null) {
                    double lat = LocationPassive.getLatitude();
                    double longi = LocationPassive.getLongitude();
                    getTheAddress(lat, longi);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Can't Get Your Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        }

        private void getTheAddress(double latitude, double longitude) {
            List<Address> addresses;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                Log.d("neel", address);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        public void OnGPS() {

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            builder.setMessage("Enable GPS").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: How to enable GPS just by clicking in "YES" instead of redirecting the user to configuration?

Comment: when u click on the yes button : mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)); explicit intent will be fired to enable the GPS . @AlitonOliveira

Answer (score 0):

some of these ans are now out of date, so im answering,

```
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient; //set global variable
Location currentLocation;//set global var
private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted; //set global var
 fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext()); //write this oncreate
        fetchLastLocation();  // call the funct for current location
//here is the function
private void fetchLastLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }else {
        mLocationPermissionGranted=true;
    }
    Task<Location> task= fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if(location != null){
                currentLocation =location;
               Toast.makeText(getContext(), currentLocation.getLatitude()+"" +
                        " "+currentLocation.getLongitude(), 
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//if you want to show in google maps
                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =(SupportMapFragment)
                        getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsFragment.this);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: What to do if `location == null`?

Comment: Fused location provider is best to get location also you can use geo location as well,,, location may be null due to different reason may be you are not connected to network so in this case you need to take care of internet connectivity,, if location is null you can pass users a message of what ever the reason is. Or you can call this functiona multiple times unless you location is not null.

Comment: Thanks! There may be a lot of situations. I experienced this problem on old emulators (and didn't resolve it. Even `LocationManager` didn't help). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52587361/fusedlocationclient-not-calling-onlocationresult, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521121/locationavailability-no-location-available.

Answer (score -1):

By using FusedLocationProviderApi which is the latest API and the best among the available possibilities to get location in Android.
add this in build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

you can get full source code by this url
http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/

Answer (score -1):

Recently refactored to obtain the location of the code, learn some good ideas, and finally achieved a relatively perfect library and Demo.

```
//request all valid provider(network/gps)
private boolean requestAllProviderUpdates() {
    checkRuntimeEnvironment();
    checkPermission();

    if (isRequesting) {
        EasyLog.d("Request location update is busy");
        return false;
    }


    long minTime = getCheckTimeInterval();
    float minDistance = getCheckMinDistance();

    if (mMapLocationListeners == null) {
        mMapLocationListeners = new HashMap<>();
    }

    mValidProviders = getValidProviders();
    if (mValidProviders == null || mValidProviders.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not available provider.");
    }

    for (String provider : mValidProviders) {
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if (location == null) {
                    EasyLog.e("LocationListener callback location is null.");
                    return;
                }
                printf(location);
                mLastProviderTimestamp = location.getTime();

                if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    finishResult(location);
                } else {
                    doLocationResult(location);
                }

                removeProvider(location.getProvider());
                if (isEmptyValidProviders()) {
                    requestTimeoutMsgInit();
                    removeUpdates();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };
        getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, locationListener);
        mMapLocationListeners.put(provider, locationListener);
        EasyLog.d("Location request %s provider update.", provider);
    }
    isRequesting = true;
    return true;
}

//remove request update
public void removeUpdates() {
    checkRuntimeEnvironment();

    LocationManager locationManager = getLocationManager();
    if (mMapLocationListeners != null) {
        Set<String> keys = mMapLocationListeners.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            LocationListener locationListener = mMapLocationListeners.get(key);
            if (locationListener != null) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                EasyLog.d("Remove location update, provider is " + key);
            }
        }
        mMapLocationListeners.clear();
        isRequesting = false;
    }
}

//Compared with the last successful position, to determine whether you need to filter
private boolean isNeedFilter(Location location) {
    checkLocation(location);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        float distance = location.distanceTo(mLastLocation);
        if (distance < getCheckMinDistance()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (location.getAccuracy() >= mLastLocation.getAccuracy()
                && distance < location.getAccuracy()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (location.getTime() <= mLastProviderTimestamp) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void doLocationResult(Location location) {
    checkLocation(location);

    if (isNeedFilter(location)) {
        EasyLog.d("location need to filtered out, timestamp is " + location.getTime());
        finishResult(mLastLocation);
    } else {
        finishResult(location);
    }
}

//Return to the finished position
private void finishResult(Location location) {
    checkLocation(location);

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
    long time = location.getTime();
    String provider = location.getProvider();

    if (mLocationResultListeners != null && !mLocationResultListeners.isEmpty()) {
        String format = "Location result:<%f, %f> Accuracy:%f Time:%d Provider:%s";
        EasyLog.i(String.format(format, latitude, longitude, accuracy, time, provider));

        mLastLocation = location;
        synchronized (this) {
            Iterator<LocationResultListener> iterator =  mLocationResultListeners.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                LocationResultListener listener = iterator.next();
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onResult(location);
                }
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Complete code: https://github.com/bingerz/FastLocation/blob/master/fastlocationlib/src/main/java/cn/bingerz/fastlocation/FastLocation.java

*Each request to complete the location, it is best to removeUpdates, otherwise the phone status bar will always display the positioning icon.

Answer (score -1):

After seeing all the answers, and question (**Simplest and Robust**). I got clicked about only library [Android-ReactiveLocation](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation).

When i made an location tracking app. Then i realized that its very typical to handle location tracking with optimised with battery.

So i want tell freshers and also developers who don't want to maintain their location code with future optimisations. Use this library.

```
ReactiveLocationProvider locationProvider = new 

    ReactiveLocationProvider(context);
    locationProvider.getLastKnownLocation()
        .subscribe(new Consumer<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Location location) {
                doSthImportantWithObtainedLocation(location);
            }
        });
```

**Dependencies to put in app level build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location2:2.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4' //you can use newer GMS version if you need
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:2.0.5' //you can override RxJava version if you need
}
```

**Pros to use this lib:**

- This lib is **and will be** actively maintained.
- You dont worry about battery optimisation. As developers have done their best.
- Easy installation, put dependency and play.
- easily connect to Play Services API
- obtain last known location
- subscribe for location updates use
- location settings API
- manage geofences
- geocode location to list of addresses
- activity recognition
- use current place API fetch place
- autocomplete suggestions